# What is the difference between "Rabb" رب (Lord) and Ilah اله(God) in Qur'an?

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy

What is the difference between "Rabb" رب (Lord) and Ilah اله(God)  in Qur'an  ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Quran, "Rabb" (رب) and "Ilah" (اله) are two distinct terms that are often used to refer to different aspects of the divine and have specific meanings:

**Rabb (رب):**

"Rabb" is typically translated as "Lord" or "Sustainer" in English.
It refers to God in His role as the Creator, Sustainer, Nurturer, and Provider of all that exists.

When "Rabb" is used, it emphasizes God's attributes related to His care, guidance, and nurturing of His creation.

For example, when Muslims say "Rabb al-'Alamin" (رب العالمين), it means "Lord of the worlds" and highlights God's authority and providence over all of creation.

**Ilah (اله):**

"Ilah" is typically translated as "God" or "Deity" in English.
It refers to the concept of divinity or an object of worship, which could be a deity or anything that people may associate with divinity.

In the Islamic context, "Ilah" is often used to emphasize the oneness of God (Tawhid) and to reject the worship of any other deities or false gods.

When the term "Ilah" is used in the Quran, it is often to assert that there is no deity worthy of worship except Allah (Allah being the name of God in Islam).

Comment: The sole name of Allah in the book of Qur'an is "Al-Rahman". The first part of the name is "Al rahem" that is The womb. Therefore, we can accept calling Him The Mother/Father/God ONE.